# Почему сложение цифр (символов) выдает неправильное число?

Tags: c++

```
unsigned long long year;
str = "17.08.1980 03:12:43";
year = int(str[6] + str[7] + str[8] + str[9]);
std::cout << year << std::endl;
```

Выводит не 1980, а 210

Comment: Выводит `210`. Где и как это вы сумели получить `160`? И почему вы ожидали `1980`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так, посмотрим, значение:

`str[6]` - `'1'` - `49`,
`str[7]` - `'9'` - `57`,
`str[8]` - `'8'` - `56`,
`str[9]` - `'0'` - `48`.
В сумме 210.

Если бы вы хотели сделать новую строку из этих символов, а не просто сумму их целочисленных значений, то надо было делать именно строку:

```
std::cout << ::std::string{str[6], str[7], str[8], str[9]} << std::endl;
```

Comment: можно же вроде так:  `std::string{std::begin(str)+6, std::begin(str)+10}`

Answer (score 2):

Не понятно что из себя представляет `str`, но все же:

```
year = (str[9] - '0') + (str[8] - '0')*10 
       + (str[7] - '0')*100 + (str[6] - '0')*1000;
```

а вы получали просто сумму целочисленных значений этих символов, а эти значения не совпадают с числом что вы видите.

Answer (score 2):

вы выводите сумму кодов этих символов, чтоб получить цифру нужно код '0' из символа вычесть, а дальше собираем число

```
int main()
{
    unsigned long long year(0);
    string str = "17.08.1980 03:12:43";
    for (int i = 6;i <= 9;++i)
    {
        year = year * 10 + str[i] - '0';
    }
    std::cout << year << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: больше всего меня устрашает длинное целое для года )

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned long long year;
const char *str = "17.08.1980 03:12:43";
std::sscanf(str, "%*d.%*d.%llu", &year);
std::cout << year << std::endl;
```